# The Non-rectifiability of The Argument Principle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

The argument principle states that given a closed rectifiable Jordan curve $L$, suppose $g(z)$ is analytic on $\overline{I(L)}$, while $f(z)$ is analytic on $\overline{I(L)}$ except for a finite amount of poles in $I(L)$ at $b_1,...,b_n$. Moreover, suppose $f(z)$ has A-points at $a_1,...,a_m$, but none on $L$ itself. Then

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L g(z)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-A}dz=\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \alpha_k g(a_k)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \beta_k g(b_k)$$where $\alpha_k$ is the order of $a_k$ and $\beta_k$ is the order of $b_k$.

Let $L$ be defined by $[\delta_1,\delta_2]$x$[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]$. Thus, $L$ can be decomposed into $\Gamma_n, \forall n=1,2,3,4$, where $L=(\Gamma_2+\Gamma_3-(\Gamma_1+\Gamma_4)$.The parametric form is $\Gamma_1: z=\delta_1+it, \epsilon_2≤t≤\epsilon_1$ , $\Gamma_2: z=t+i\epsilon_1, \delta_1≤t≤\delta_2$, $\Gamma_3: z=\delta_2+it, \epsilon_1≤t≤\epsilon_2$, and lastly $\Gamma_4: z=t+i\epsilon_2, \delta_2≤t≤\delta_1$. Thus, $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L g(z)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-A}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_2+\Gamma_3-(\Gamma_1+\Gamma_4)} g(z)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-A}dz$$

and then letting $\delta_1\rightarrow -\infty$, $\delta_2\rightarrow \infty$, $\epsilon_1\rightarrow -\infty$, and $\epsilon_2\rightarrow \infty$, a non rectifiable curve is obtained.

> Does the Argument Principle hold if $L$ is the non-rectifiable Jordan curve described above, such that: $$sup\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |z_k-z_{k-1}|=\infty$$

Comment: What's the definition of the integral over a non-rectifiable curve?

Comment: The curve is a rectangle $L: [\delta_1,\delta_2]$x$[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]$ and then letting $\delta_1\rightarrow -\infty$, $\delta_2\rightarrow \infty$, $\epsilon_1\rightarrow -\infty$, and $\epsilon_2\rightarrow \infty$. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: ??? If you take that rectangle and then let those things tend to infinity you don't get a non-rectifiable curve in the limit, you don't get any curve at all.

Comment: A rectifiable curve is defined as a curve with finite length, namely $$sup\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |z_k-z_{k-1}|<\infty$$ Thus a non-rectifiable curve had non-finite or infinite length specified by the the latter case $$sup\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |z_k-z_{k-1}|=\infty$$ @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: I understand what the word rectifiable means. What _curve_ are you talking about? You said you took that rectangle and let the corners tend to infinity - that does not result in a curve.

Comment: I agree that this is not a curve regarding wide-sense differentiability, however, I wanted to know if the Argument Principle is still valid for such a construct. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: _What_ is not a curve? Can you name me a single point on this thing, whatever it is?

Comment: The statement of the problem has been adjusted accordingly. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: You still don't have a curve in the limit.

Comment: What would it become?@RobertIsrael

Comment: It just goes to complex $\infty$, a point of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Is there any technique to construct an $L$, such that it includes the whole of the complex plane, which is still classified as a curve?@RobertIsrael

Comment: Would this be rectified by stating that the area of the region becomes arbitrarily large, however, not infinite? @DavidC.Ullrich